# Bootstrap editable shows editable-loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I get this strange div while I'm trying to load my editable field.

I can't find somewhere how to disable this without changing in the editable source code.

Does anyone have a clue why I'm getting that?

This is what it looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone else is having this problem in the future, I looked at the sourcecode and I only needed to add:

loading : '' between the {} tags

Comment: I am actually having a simular problem. Can you please post the relevant code fragment and explain what you've changed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using an older version of Bootstrap Editable. Now it is called X-Editable, which you can found here http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/.

Comment: Seems you are correct: ["This plugin no longer supported! Please use x-editable instead! 
https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable"](https://github.com/vitalets/bootstrap-editable)